# How to recursively iterate through a list of 3-tuples in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming

I have a list of 3-tuples `[(Int, Int, Int)]`

I have written the following helper functions.

```
--This function is used to check if the first element is over 20    
checkValue :: (Int, Int, Int) -> Bool  
checkValue (x, _, _) = x  > 20


--This function is used to set the 3-tuple to return (50, 50, 50)
setValue :: (Int, Int, Int) -> (Int, Int, Int)
setValue a = (50, 50, 50)
```

My goal is to iterate through the list of 3-tuples and apply my helper functions.

For each item in list

- Run checkValue.
- If checkValue = true, apply setValue to the current tuple.
- Continue

So basically if I have this `[(0, 0, 0)(30,15,0)]`
It would return `[(0, 0, 0)(50, 50, 50)]`

Could someone point me in the right direction, been stuck on this for a while.

Comment: Tip: [`map :: (a ->b) -> [a] -> [b]`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a-%3Eb%29+-%3E+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+%5Bb%5D).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use recursion then you may do as follows;

```
modif :: [(Int, Int, Int)] -> [(Int, Int, Int)]
modif []                 = []
modif (t@(x, _, _) : ts) = case x > 20 of
                           True -> (50, 50, 50) : modif ts
                           _    -> t : modif ts

*Main> modif [(0, 0, 0),(30,15,0)]
[(0,0,0),(50,50,50)]
```

The `t@(x, _, _)` portion stands for pattern maching `x` on the first element of the tuple and also naming the whole thing as `t`.